# How does boost serialization actually save const object

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, constants, boost-serialization

Considering the following example of serialization, how does boost cope with saving data when this data is const and the serialization function is not a const function ?

Is there a const cast somewhere ?

```
  struct Settings
  {
    Settings();
    uint32_t    buffers_size;
    uint32_t    messages;
  };

  template < class Archive >
  void serialize(Archive& ar, Settings& settings, unsigned int /*version*/)
  {
    using boost::serialization::make_nvp;
    ar 
      & make_nvp< uint32_t >("buffers_size", settings.buffers_size )
      & make_nvp< uint32_t >("messages", settings.messages);
  }
```

Comment: My guess is that it ignores `const` and `volatile` qualifiers, as these have not really much bearing to writing things to a file, network stream, etc.

Comment: If you need const correctness, you can [split serialize into `save` (`const`) and `load` (not `const`)](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/serialization/doc/serialization.html#splitting).

Comment: @LucTouraille: the prblem with load/save is that the code is splitted in two, which is hard in terms of maintenance

Comment: Sure, if the serialization/deserialization are perfectly symmetrical, it makes sense to write them with a single function. I just spent some time browsing through Boost code to see how constness is handled by the serialization library, but I did not found a definitive answer yet. I guess a `const_cast` is plausible, but then it means one should be careful not to modify the serialized object in the `serialize` function, because it would open the door to undefined behavior when serializing a const object.

Comment: Yeah, the other option would be to copy the data, but I'm not sure it makes sense in terms of performances/memory usage. Also it requires a copy constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the constness is indeed casted away before saving the object. I think the relevant code is in `oserializer.hpp`:

```
template<class Archive, class T>
BOOST_DLLEXPORT void oserializer<Archive, T>::save_object_data(
    basic_oarchive & ar,    
    const void *x
) const {
    // make sure call is routed through the highest interface that might
    // be specialized by the user.
    BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(boost::is_const< T >::value == false);
    boost::serialization::serialize_adl(
        boost::serialization::smart_cast_reference<Archive &>(ar),
        * static_cast<T *>(const_cast<void *>(x)),
        version()
    );
}
```

Before this method is called, the serialized object reference is turned into a `const void *`, corresponding to the second parameter here. The constness of this pointer is casted away, and the resulting pointer is casted to the appropriate pointer type, which is then dereferenced.

This raises the question of the possibility of invoking undefined behavior when trying to serialize a `const` object: if the `serialize` member/free function somehow modifies the object, then creating a `const` object and saving it to an archive would be undefined behavior, and go unnoticed at compile-time!

If you split the function into `save` and `load`, then you must mark `save` as `const`, which prevents you from accidentally modifying the object.